# How to create or represent a new database id on the client?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, database, single-page-application, uniqueidentifier

I have a Single Page Application that uses a JavaScript grid. This grid requires a unique id for every row inserted in the grid. I am struggling with finding an acceptable way to add an item to this grid before I receive a unique id from a server side database transaction.

I originally tried doing an ajax call before updating the grid. This ajax call would insert the data into a SQL Server database and return the new id to the client.  Then I would add the row to the grid. This created a delay before the grid would be updated. From a user experience standpoint, this became unacceptable.

Next I tried to create a temporary id (a negative number to avoid conflicts) when the user created an item to add to the grid. I would immediately add it to the grid with this temporary id. I would then do my ajax call, return the correct database id, and update the grid a second time.

This has proved to be a logistical nightmare, as sometimes the user might do another action before the id has been updated, resulting in incorrect ids floating around. The complexity of the system has also created requirements to add ugly, special case code throughout the entire code base that I would like to eliminate.

Is there a way to create a database id on the client side or another established solution to handle this scenario?

Comment: Can you make the ids on the grid not correspond to the database ids? You could just add the database ids in a hidden input field on the grid.

Comment: @jle This is a possibility. I should maybe edit my question to explain that I have an entire client-side database that mirrors the server side database that is the underpinnings of my grid. This would mean the client-side database would be identical to the server side database other than ids. I could see this also becoming logistically complex, but it might be a better solution than what I'm currently doing.

Comment: Can you post the code for your grid and ajax call?

Comment: What does the "ID" correspond to in your db?  Is it an auto-incrementing number in some table column?  Perhaps a column with the IDENTITY property?

Comment: @jle The grid is SlickGrid. I'd be a bit hard pressed to know exactly what code to post for the ajax call (other than saying it's done via jQuery). This is a very large enterprise level software suite for power plants that follows a custom framework. The ajax call is in an entire file of nothing but ajax calls, where most of the pertinent information is passed in from multiple other files.

Comment: @DMason Usually it is a non-auto incremented primary key. A few newer tables use auto increment. An older programmer that is no longer working on the project had odd trust issues with auto-incrementing fields, so he created a table that stores the next available id for every other table in the database. We are willing to restructure this if it will help this issue (some of us are more than willing...)

Comment: Since you may be willing to do some restructuring...if you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you might look into using a [SEQUENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091(v=sql.110).aspx).  However, I'm not sure if this is any better than your existing table with "next available id".